# Write the Job execution steps to a Text file in TOS 7.3

Tags: talend

I want to write to whole execution process of a Job to a text file in Talend Open Studio 7.3 because in Enterprise edition it is already logged but I am not sure where to find the execution log in Talend Open Studio

so I had thought of writing the execution of the job to a Text file

Can anyone please guide me how to do it[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below process to get the logs of the job in a file.

1. Select the job
2. Select Stats & Logs in the left pannel of the same window
3. Uncheck Use Project Settings if checked
4. Select the type of log you need (tStatCatcher/ tLogCatcher/tFlowMeterCatcher). You can select all three as well
5. Provide path of the file and file names

[image]

If you need detailed logs, you can also have tJava and customize your logs and direct it to a file

Comment: I had tried with the steps you had given but it writes only to the stats_file.txt but No logs_file.txt is written is there a particular reason for it like on error or warning only the logs_file.txt will be written